"Is the Zohar/Kabbalah/Sefirot Shittuf/Heresy/Avodah Zara" - do these questions HAVE to always come up in "Related"?
Is there any way to remove them, or at least give them a lower "relevance score" for the related suggestions? See my justification below:
While everyone agrees it is important to establish that the sefirot are not shittuf or heresy, having those question prominently come up every. single. time. a kabbalah/sefirot question is asked is problematic for several reasons:

It's almost always irrelevant. Just because a question is about a topic, doesn't mean that it's about the legitimacy of that topic! Imagine if every single question on gemara was linked to a question "is the gemara a legitimate record of the oral torah or just something the rabbis made up"
These questions, and their answers can be considered inappropriate/offensive to some, and therefore not something many people want shoved in their face, or associated with their questions. It feels bordering on "cooling the waters" alá Amalek, letzanut etc. Imagine if every single question even slightly related to modern orthodox has a "is the legitimacy of the modern orthodox movement any better than the reform movement" related-question come up, I'm sure a lot of people would complain.
The topic is controversial, with many big Gedolim on both sides*, so to say that it is important to not do anything to hide these questions is likely something that is coming from a political position (i.e. biased), rather than pure intellectual honesty and the pursuit of truth. Yes, your Gadol was very suspicious of the Zohar, and you feel obligated to spread the word, but my Gadol considered the Zohar to be among the most sacred texts in the cannon, and speaking against it is a very grave thing to do. Can I be thought about too? Imagine if every single question on this site brought up a question on the very legitimacy of Judaism. Some would say it's important because we need to be intellectually honest, but surely this is not normative thinking and is likely only going to be Christians or Atheists who would be in favour of such an argument. The Rabbonim would consider this question rather problematic, possibly heretical depending on exactly how it is asked and answered.

I am not asking to censor the questions, just asking if there is anything we can do to untie them from every single Kabbalah question (for which they are mostly completely irrelevant!), it's tiresome, upsetting and not at all necessary - if people want to know, they can search for them easily.
* And I think it's uncontroversial to say that, by proportion and "fame", there are many many more on the side that it is legitimate, which is to say that even though there might be a high proportion of orthodox folk here (especially computer literate, internet-accessing ones) who might not hold the sentiments of this post, it is still relevant to include the wider Orthodox world.

Can you give an example of a linkage that you think would be better off suppressed? It's certainly not on every single kabbala related question. For example, I don't see any such linkage here https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/145050/759

@DoubleAA my latest question using the kabbalah tag for example: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/146010/derivation-of-the-number-600-000-in-zohar. "Every single" is an exaggeration, yes, but not much of one. The "
Why isn't the Kabbalistic doctrine of Sefirot considered Shittuf if the Christian Trinity is?" question gets linked a lot for example, I've seen it many many times on very unrelated questions. "Is one a heretic if he does not believe in Kabbalah?". Authenticity of the Zohar comes up a lot whenever the Zohar is mentioned

They are among the top voted questions in the tag kabbalah https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysticism-kabbalah?tab=Votes and the tag zohar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zohar?tab=Votes

@DoubleAA I know. I am happy that other tags' top questions are not "is this topic heretical". I would complain about how that causes the Related questions to be problematic too. I ask that you try to put yourself in my shoes - what topic are you glad doesn't have such questions top voted? What would you do if they were? Your top tag seems to be halacha; wouldn't it be annoying if the top most voted question was "is halacha really binding or is it just the rabbis inventions, trying to control us"? Wouldn't it wear away at your soul after seeing it come up in most questions you post on halacha?

The "related" posts you ask about are automatically generated by StackExchange by some algorithm, probably relating to tags, keywords, and post scores (many of the posts you refer to indeed have high vote scores).
The mods have no manual control over it. SE would have to code up something special for us, which seems to me to be unlikely to happen anytime soon.
This is not to dismiss your concerns, just to answer the question of ability factually.

If a particular question has an inflammatory title, you could consider editing it to be less inflammatory in the sidebar. But as with all editing do make sure the title is still accurate and sufficiently descriptive to be helpful. Edits should always be productive not destructive.

Thanks I appreciate this. I won't upvote because upvotes work different on meta, but otherwise +1 to you
